# Set value in row based on (great)* grandfather row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
   SelfID  ParentID 
0       A       nan
1       B         A
2       X       nan
3       C         B
4       D         C
5       Y         X
```

You can see that there are chains linking back to an ultimate parent: e.g. `D->C->B->A`.

I would like to have a separate column with the ultimate ancestor for that group, so that I can use `groupby` on them as a whole. So the `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` rows would all have a `A` in this last column.

The only way I can think of doing this to loop through, using a dictionary to store the value of the parent.

Is there a better method, perhaps one that doesn't involve looping?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that still iterates, but the number of iterations will be determined by the maximum number of ancestral levels rather than by the number of items in the sample. Depending on your data, this may be better. The idea is to keep joining one generation to the next until you reach a generation with no one in it.

```
ancestry = pd.DataFrame(dict(SelfID=["A","B","X","C","D","Y"], ParentID=[np.nan, "A",np.nan,"B","C","X"]))
ancestry = ancestry.set_index("SelfID")
earliest_ancestor = ancestry.rename(columns={"ParentID":"EarliestAncestorID"})

while True:
    # Join the current to the previous generation
    earliest_ancestor = pd.merge(earliest_ancestor, earliest_ancestor, left_on="EarliestAncestorID", right_index=True, how="left", suffixes=["_child", ""])
    earliest_generation = earliest_ancestor.EarliestAncestorID
    # Fillna to keep the earliest known ancestor
    earliest_ancestor = earliest_ancestor.fillna(method="ffill", axis=1).drop("EarliestAncestorID_child", axis=1)
    # If no one in this generation, we can stop going back
    if earliest_generation.isnull().all():
        break

ancestry = pd.concat((ancestry, earliest_ancestor), axis=1).reset_index()
# If no ancestors, self is the earliest ancestor
ancestry.loc[:, "EarliestAncestorID"] =  ancestry.EarliestAncestorID.where(ancestry.EarliestAncestorID.notnull(), ancestry.SelfID)
print ancestry
```

Which loops 3 times and gives:

```
  SelfID ParentID EarliestAncestorID
0      A      NaN                  A
1      B        A                  A
2      X      NaN                  X
3      C        B                  A
4      D        C                  A
5      Y        X                  X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

def derive_ancestor(df):
        id = dict(zip(df['SelfID'],df['ParentID']))

        def ancestor(k):
                return k if id[k] is nan else ancestor(id[k])

        return [ ancestor(s) for s in df['SelfID'] ]

dframe = pd.DataFrame(data={'SelfID':('A','B','X','C','D','Y'),
                           'ParentID': (nan,'A',nan,'B','C','X')})
dframe.insert(2,'AncestorID',derive_ancestor(dframe))
print dframe
```